# Why was this minion summoned?

Tags: hearthstone

I am referring to the summoning of a 30/30 between 9:48 and 9:55 in [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4hhR2Nb1sA0&t=9m38s). I sought to identify its 9/9 precursors by going through the crafting section of my app, but I couldn’t find them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you have two [Blood of the Ancient Ones](https://hearthstone.gamepedia.com/Blood_of_The_Ancient_One) (the 9/9 minions), at the end of your turn they combine into [The Ancient One](https://hearthstone.gamepedia.com/Blood_of_The_Ancient_One) (the 30/30 minion).

Comment: This calls for one blood of the ancients on turn 9. Then faceless manipulator and Drakkari Enchanter on turn 10!

Comment: Harder, but double the fun: turn 9: blood of the ancients. Turn 10: Faceless Manipulator, Coin, Two Drakkari Enchanters. I would so like to kill the Lich King with it!

Comment: @Ludi if you google "blood of the ancients drakkari enchanter" you can see videos of the end of turn effect not triggering twice. You only get one of the 30/30 :( Similarly, two drakkari enchanter do not make end of turn effects go 4x, you still only get the 2x bonus from one of them.